# How to use split() in python with multiple delimeters including whitespace

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to split below string : at comma, whitespace and pipe,

```
str1 = "HSQCV,feedback.fetch(stat[c[i]]) 3453 54f|note"
```

i need to get my output list `str1` after splitting as:

```
['HSQCV', 'feedback.fetch(stat[c[i]])', '3453', '54f', 'note']
```

Comment: You need to start by putting quotes around the assignment to `str1`.

Comment: You could try `re.split`.... could the parameter list of `fetch` in this example have more `,`, and should those also be split?

Comment: @tobias_k no only at whitespaces comma pipe

Answer (score 6):

maybe u can try using Regular expression

```
re.split('\s|,|\|', str1)
```

Comment: that is the way. It is little known due to it being a somewhat recent addition to the 're' module - on Python 3.7 IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code , it should work

```
str1 = "HSQCV,feedback.fetch(stat[c[i]]) 3453 54f|note"
str1=str1.replace(",", " ")
str1=str1.replace("|"," ")
str1.split()
```

Comment: Please don't paste pictures of code. It's not really any harder to copy & paste the text, and it's much easier for everyone else in that form.